# Does anyone know how to make input work properly on iOS devices in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, inputfield

So iOS has some major bugs with input objects in iFrames, the upshot of which is that if you use input fields in a Visualforce page in the Salesforce1 mobile app, you get to deal with those bugs.

If you put an input field in a VF page, type in it, then click to move the cursor, you'll no longer be able to type until you hide and show the keyboard. My question is has anyone found a work around for this?

ContentEditiable elements suffer from the same issues.

This page is enough to demonstrate the problem:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Using `window.open()` to get a non-framed window does result in things working correctly, but that's not going to cut it for the majority of use cases.

Comment: There is [a blog post by Bob Buzzard](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.nz/2014/03/salesforce1-and-visualforce-things-i.html) that suggests using the HTML5 type attribute rather than <apex:inputField />

Comment: Unfortunately even regular input fields have this issue inside iFrames on iOS.

Comment: looks like it's a "known" bug in safari? (http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2527401 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124340/cant-type-into-html-input-fields-on-ios-after-clicking-twice)

Comment: Yeah it is, but it's been there for ages it seems to I can't see Apple rectifying this... which is going to be a big thing for Developers working with Salesforce1!

Comment: I've been told this code was worked on in the webkit to be released with iOS8, so there is some hope. Now we just need them to ship it.

Comment: @LaceySnr did you happen to come across a solution to this? I'm enjoying the same problem at the moment.

Comment: @Daft It's not something I've come back to yet, now for mobile pages I'm actually using remoting with KnockoutJS as I find it to be a lot faster for the end user. For an example of using KnockoutJS you can check out my blog post: http://www.laceysnr.com/2014/11/get-started-with-knockoutjs-on.html

Comment: There is open issue on salesforce community. If this issue is affecting you please vote. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5l1AAC

Answer (score 1):

Using < apex:inputText / > or HTML-5 input component < input type="text"/ > resolves the issue. I tested this out on IOS 8

Comment: Haven't gotten around to testing this yet, will mark accepted once I have!

Answer (score 1):

Suggested answer from SFDCBAT does NOT work.

Two possible known workarounds are:
1. to use window.open(url), which doesn't use iframe,
2. dismiss virtual keyboard or use prev/next button to jump on next field

Reference to known issue on success.salesforce.com: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5l1AAC

Answer (score 0):

I tried by adding docType="html-5.0" into  and use  but the problem still not resolves. Could you please give us more details?

Comment: Zah, since you are after more details rather than answering, i suggest to post this as a comment (but you need to earn reps for it) or raise a new question and link this one.. Thanks.